# New to Hibernate/JPA: java.lang.NullPointerException filtering on table primary key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm new to Hibernate/JPA. I wrote a simple demo project to start understanding the technology. I have this problem: everything works fine but filtering the persistence object on table primary key field. Every other field can be used to filter the objects without any problem even when I use multiple filters.

This is the simple demo code I wrote:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<BaRoles> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(BaRoles.class);

Root<BaRoles> root = criteriaQuery.from(BaRoles.class);

criteriaQuery.select(root).where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("rocode"), 78));
//criteriaQuery.select(root).where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("rodescri"), "xxxxxxxx")); <-- Works fine

Query<BaRoles> query = session.createQuery(criteriaQuery);

List<BaRoles> roles = query.getResultList(); // <-- Returns nothing filtering rocode, correctly returns obejcts when filtering rodescri

for (int roleCounter = 0; roleCounter < roles.size(); roleCounter++) {
    BaRoles role = (BaRoles) roles.get(roleCounter);
}
```

This is the complete stack trace:

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.internal.BasicValuedPathInterpretation.from(BasicValuedPathInterpretation.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitBasicValuedPath(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:747)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitBasicValuedPath(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.domain.SqmBasicValuedSimplePath.accept(SqmBasicValuedSimplePath.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitComparisonPredicate(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:1545)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitComparisonPredicate(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.predicate.SqmComparisonPredicate.accept(SqmComparisonPredicate.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.visitQuerySpec(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:364)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.internal.StandardSqmSelectTranslator.visitSelectStatement(StandardSqmSelectTranslator.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.internal.StandardSqmSelectTranslator.translate(StandardSqmSelectTranslator.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.buildCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.resolveCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.performList(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.doList(QuerySqmImpl.java:413)
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractQuery.list(AbstractQuery.java:1356)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:136)
    at com.xxxx.xxxxx.mavenproject1.BaRoleManager.readWithFilter(BaRoleManager.java:153)
    at com.xxxx.xxxxx.mavenproject1.BaRoleManager.main(BaRoleManager.java:201)

And this is the BaRoles class (Generate with JPA):

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.TableGenerator;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@Entity
@Table(name = "ba_roles")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "BaRoles.findAll", query = "SELECT b FROM BaRoles b"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "BaRoles.findByRocode", query = "SELECT b FROM BaRoles b WHERE b.rocode = :rocode"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "BaRoles.findByRodescri", query = "SELECT b FROM BaRoles b WHERE b.rodescri = :rodescri"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "BaRoles.findByCpccchk", query = "SELECT b FROM BaRoles b WHERE b.cpccchk = :cpccchk"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "BaRoles.findByRodescriEng", query = "SELECT b FROM BaRoles b WHERE b.rodescriEng = :rodescriEng")
})
public class BaRoles implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    //@TableGenerator(name = "roleGenerator", table = "cpwarn", allocationSize = 1, pkColumnName = "tablecode", valueColumnName = "autonum", pkColumnValue = "prog\\ba_roles", schema="dbo", initialValue = 0)
    @TableGenerator(name = "roleGenerator", table = "cpwarn", allocationSize = 1, pkColumnName = "tablecode", valueColumnName = "autonum", pkColumnValue = "prog\\ba_roles")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "roleGenerator")
    @Column(name = "ROCODE", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Integer rocode;
    @Column(name = "RODESCRI")
    private String rodescri;
    @Column(name = "cpccchk")
    private String cpccchk;
    @Column(name = "RODESCRI_ENG")
    private String rodescriEng;

    public BaRoles() {
    }

    public BaRoles(Integer rocode) {
        this.rocode = rocode;
    }

    public Integer getRocode() {
        return rocode;
    }

    public void setRocode(Integer rocode) {
        this.rocode = rocode;
    }

    public String getRodescri() {
        return rodescri;
    }

    public void setRodescri(String rodescri) {
        this.rodescri = rodescri;
    }

    public String getCpccchk() {
        return cpccchk;
    }

    public void setCpccchk(String cpccchk) {
        this.cpccchk = cpccchk;
    }

    public String getRodescriEng() {
        return rodescriEng;
    }

    public void setRodescriEng(String rodescriEng) {
        this.rodescriEng = rodescriEng;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (rocode != null ? rocode.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof BaRoles)) {
            return false;
        }
        BaRoles other = (BaRoles) object;
        if ((this.rocode == null && other.rocode != null) || (this.rocode != null && !this.rocode.equals(other.rocode))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.xxxx.xxxx.mavenproject1.BaRoles[ rocode=" + rocode + " ]";
    }

}
```

Comment: You should give more information. The stacktrace for the NullPointer exception you mention in the title for example. Also if possible the entity BaRoles code, to see the configuration.

Comment: I added class and stack trace

Comment: You should gain some more familiarity with Java basics before diving into JPA-type projects. You shouldn't be casting list values when using generics, and you should almost always iterate over a collection using `for (BaRoles role : roles)`.

Comment: Ok, but it doesn't concern with the question, I just want to know why filtering on a field works fine and why on another it doesn't... it's just a 5-min demo, almost every modern editor can make the conversion you suggest automatically, don't loose time on secondary things, stay on question focus please

Comment: Try to acces property with metamodel, replace criteriaQuery.select(root).where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("rocode"), 78)) by criteriaQuery.select(root).where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(BadRoles_.rocode), 78)) if you dont have metamodel activate this feaure. (in eclipse is project proerties / JPA / canonical metamodel and select src folder)

Comment: Ty JLazar0, unfortunately nothing changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Reverted Hibernate version from 6.0.0 alpha 4 to 5.4.12 final (Maven repository). Everything works as expected. Thank you everyone for your time and effort.